# Support for Farsi/Arabic texts in Three.js

Tags: three.js, arabic, persian

I need to show some text in Persian/Arabic language. I loaded a font including characters and I used TextGeometry to create a text on the scene:

```js
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('B Zar_Regular.js', function (font) {
    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry('سلام!', {
        font: font,
        size: 1,
        height: 0.05,
        curveSegments: 12,
    });
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, material);
    textMesh.position.x = 15;
    scene.add(textMesh);
});
```

I was expecting to see `سلام!` but the output was:

[image: three.js arabic text problem]

letters are separated and order of characters is reversed mistakenly. After all it seems threejs do not support rtl languages. Am I right or I missed something? Is there any workaround as a quick solution? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've already taken the appropriate step to get RTL added to three.js (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11680). As a workaround, you could write a script to reverse your string before passing it to `TextGeometry`.

Comment: @TheJim01 reversing the string is part of solution but not all, I have read a good article about the subject and I found out the steps to solve the problem. I'm implementing the solution and testing it. I will write down an answer when it got done. Thanks for comment.

Comment: See [these rules](https://w3c.github.io/alreq/) to understand why reversing the character order is not a solution or even a part of the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I found very useful blog post [here](https://blog.mapbox.com/improving-arabic-and-hebrew-text-in-map-labels-fd184cf5ebd1) by Chris Loer. He has written a plugin ([mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-rtl-text)) that solves the problem.

**Usage example:**

```js
var rtlText = require('mapbox-gl-rtl-text');
var arabicString = "سلام";
var shapedArabicText = rtlText.applyArabicShaping(arabicString);
var readyForDisplay = rtlText.processBidirectionalText(shapedArabicText, []);
```

---

**PS:** When I used this plugin with common Farsi fonts some of letters was not shown so I add some [extra code](https://codepen.io/mahmoudinasab/pen/xzqVMx) to fix it.

```js
RtlTextHelper.farsify("سلام");
```

**Usage example:**

```js
private createTextMesh(font, text) {
        var shapedText = RtlTextHelper.farsify(text);
        var fontSize = 0.3;
        var textHieght = 0.2;
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: this.colors.label.normal,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(shapedText, {
            font: font,
            size: fontSize,
            height: 0.05,
            curveSegments: 12
        });
        var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, material);
        textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
        var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(textMesh);
        var textLength = box.max.x;
        return {
            mesh: textMesh,
            hieght: textHieght,
            font: {
                size: fontSize
            },
            length: textLength
        };
    }
```

Comment: [this link](https://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/svg-tiny-bidi/) is good too.

Comment: that didn't work for me, when I console the result it returns the right result, but three js is unable to display it as a 3d ..

Comment: Ok, it looks like some Arabic fonts won't work anyway, I was trying `Amiri` font but it didn't work, after I tried other fonts it works with your edit.

Comment: @shamaseen glad to hear that my answer helped you. you can upvote my answer (and question) if you find out it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem. Ligatures, the calligraphic strokes which connect letters, most familiar to western readers as a component of cursive English, is not optional in Arabic. Ligatures are intrinsic to the language, changing the meaning and formality of the text. The [font.js class](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/core/Font.js) is designed to take each letter (glyph) one by one and convert it to a shape path. This doesn't work in Arabic because [joining rules are complex](https://w3c.github.io/alreq/) depending on specific letter combinations.

I do not believe there is a fix that can be put in place in three.js. Although I would be anxious to know what the potential solution is as mentioned by O.P.

It may be possible to convert isolated letters to final Arabic ligatured forms [via this script](https://github.com/Accorpa/Arabic-Converter-From-and-To-Arabic-Presentation-Forms-B), or [maybe this one](http://mpcabd.xyz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/) among others. The final presentation forms  might then be sent to Three.js for display so that the ligature joins are handled already and three.js receives the final ligatured forms rather than the isolated glyphs.

It may be a simpler task to convert text to svg paths using a [text to path converter](https://github.com/shrhdk/text-to-svg) and then using the SVGLoader.js in three.js to load the letters as paths for extrusion. But this would have to be tested to ensure the conversion of text to a path handles Arabic at all and then if it does, the ligature joins will also need to be checked for accuracy.