# how to display arabic letters in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm trying to display arabic letters by using textGeometry but three js doesn't support arabic letters even i use a JSON arabic font file but still no changes. i'm using this code so if anyone knows how to encode arabic letters reading from keyboard

```js
var displayLetter = function(letter) {
  loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
  loader.load('font/Janna LT_Bold.json', function (font) {
    console.log("hello");
    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "س" , {   // formCharCode encoding from int --> char
        font: font,
        size: 2,
        height: 0.05,
        curveSegments: 12,
    });

    var fontmaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(PalmMaterials);
    var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, fontmaterial);
    textMesh.position.x = 2;
    scene.add(textMesh);
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for Farsi/Arabic texts in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920527/support-for-farsi-arabic-texts-in-three-js)

Comment: no i used the solution code but it is not defined because require function is a node js function not three js function

Comment: As I had no problem displaying your font using three.js, I'm wondering - did you save your html file as unicode? Can you post a working example which showcases the issue?

Comment: how can i save my html as unicode i don't understand i'm saving it in the server file, the problem that it doesn't show the letter i'm putting in the code "س" it display Ø^3